# start css3 animation after entire page load

Tags: animation, css

Anyone know how to start a css3 animation after the rest of the page loads completely (images and everything)?

I am using a delay right now to mimic it but this is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is beyond the scope of CSS, but it is quite simple to do with JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {/*You code here*/ }
```

Or read more about it here => http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Place your animation code in a class, lets say .animation

Then call that class on the element you wish to animate using JQuery .addclass() (http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Something like this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#element-to-animate").addClass("animation"); 
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but the code for the animations lives on my css page, how would I incorporate my css into the function?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){...}) do not wait for images to get loaded.
I would suggest $(window).load(function(){...}) instead.

Comment: please change to .element-to-animate if it's to be a class like you said. would hate for a beginner to be confused by this.

Answer (score 2):

```
   div
    {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s; 
     animation-delay: 5s;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
function atload() {dom_rdy()}window.onload=atload;
```

Paste it on the top of your js, and working with function `dom_rdy()` it will calls when dom is ready, without jQuery and others tons of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
.bodyclass div{
    some animation css code
}
```

After body load just apply `bodyclass` to the body tag, then all the divs in the page will be animatable. This solution is efficient then @Husar said, because, we need to search only for the body element after the page load is complete but in other case, we need to change all the elements class name that needs to animated.

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load(function(){...})`

works fine!

But use only when you want images to get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

@Mavericks solution works. But a much simpler solution that worked for me was:

CSS:

```
body {
   display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
(function() {
    $('body').css('display', 'block');
})();
```

or you can use show/hide. But, animation became buggy on IE10 and IE11. So, I changed the code to specifically for these browsers to:

CSS:

```
body {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
(function() {
    $('body').css('visibility', 'visible');
})();
```

I also found this: https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/

Maybe it might help someone.

Comment: Please let me know the reason before voting down, as it worked for me.