# please help me temporarily change colour of menu items in sequence on page load

Tags: html, css, menu, onload

I am working on a website which has subtle dark grey menu items on the top of every page. The menu is constructed using a list and some CSS and HTML. Currently using ID in BODY to highlight menu item which corresponds to the page your looking at.

What I am trying to achieve is that when the page loads, each menu item in the list changes in sequence from dark grey to its .hover colour for a second and then fade back to dark grey. The intention is to show the viewer that there is a menu present, yet then allow the menu to be less intrusive as styled.

**HTML (only showing the relevent bits of code)**

```
<head>
<!-- InstanceParam name="id" type="text" value="inno" -->
</head>
<body id="@@(id)@@">
        <div class="big-nav-inline"><ul>
          <li><a href="../markets.htm" class="marknav">Markets</a></li>
          <li><a href="../science-and-technology.htm" class="technav">Technology</a></li>
          <li><a href="../innovation.htm" class="innonav">Innovation</a></li>
          <li><a href="../ventures.htm" class="ventnav">Ventures</a></li>
        </ul></div>
  </body>
```

**CSS Explanation (full code is currently too bloated to paste)**

I am using the div class for positioning on the page.
I am using the class of each list item to give a different list item color on .hover
I am using `<body id="">` to highlight the current page list item and to change a border colour on the page.

Hope you can help!!!

What do i need to use to get the effect im after? Have any of you done this simply?

Kind Regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect by using CSS3 animations/transitions.

See also this post: [start css3 animation after entire page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771378/start-css3-animation-after-entire-page-load)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I could really do with a bit more of a hand! Kind Regards Paul